# what does "덕을 볼 수 있지않을까" mean

Tags: vocabulary

here is the context

Center에 섰을 때 그런 덕을 더 볼 수 있지않을까

This is from the idol survival program Produce 48.

I read the definition for 덕을 보다 and it doesn't make sense to me. if it's easier to explain in Korean, feel free to do that.

Answer (score 2):

1) 덕 = forgivingness, tolerance

2) 후덕한 인상 = tolerant face

3) 덕을 쌓다.

helping other, having mercy or doing a person a kindness.

(That is, if we help other without receiving money, then he receive
a reward in the future.)

4) 덕을 보다 = 덕 보다 : Compare 도움 받다 = receive other's help.
덕을 보다 has wider usage.

오늘 니 덕에 잘 놀았어. Today is exciting by your supporting.

가난한 그 애 이번에 검사 됐어. she is poor, but she become a
prosecutor in this time

할머니가 고생해서 키웠는데, 그녀는 할머니 덕 본거야 Even though she
was brought up under poverty, she obtains a benefit from grandmother.

Comment: ...덕을 보다 has nothing to do with "positive attitude".  The translation of your final example makes no sense.

Comment: I see. I modified.